# Modal Won't Close Selectize Rails 6

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, selectize.js

Hi I am following along with an old go rails video for selective and trying to update for rails 6

I have an item which belongs to a series.

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord

belongs_to :series

end
```

a series has many items

```
class Series < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :items
end
```

in the item form I am using selective to find or create by

```
<%= form_for @item do |form| %>
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= form.select :series_id, Series.all.pluck(:name, :id), {}, { class: "selectize" } %>
        </div>
....
```

I have no problem with my code except once I have created the new series I hit the following issue in my console and the modal wont close.

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade series-modal" id="series-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="SeriesModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="SeriesModal">Add series</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <%= form_for Series.new do |f| %>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :name %>
            <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.collection_select(:account_id, Account.all, :id, :name ) %>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The JS

```
<!-- JS -->
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function() {
    var selectizeCallback = null;

    $(".series-modal").on("hide.bs.modal", function(e) {
        if (selectizeCallback != null) {
            selectizeCallback();
            selectizeCallback = null;
        }

        $("#new_series").trigger("reset");
        $.rails.enableFormElements($("#new_series"));
    });

    $("#new_series").on("submit", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: $(this).attr("action"),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(response) {
                selectizeCallback({value: response.id, text: response.name});
                $(".series-modal").modal('toggle');
            }
        });
    });

    $(".selectize").selectize({
        create: function(input, callback) {
            selectizeCallback = callback;

            $(".series-modal").modal();
            $("#series_name").val(input);
        }
    });
});
```

I am sure it is something funky in my js in relation to the way bootstrap handles closing the modal now

Your help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found later that this was in relation to the location of the actual code on the page.

make sure that modal 1 is before modal 2 on the html page.